# Apache POI 3.9: row.getCell() null on last row when autofilter is on

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I am facing a strange behavior reading an excel file (xlsx) with apache poi 3.9: when the file has autofilter set on a workbook, the call to `row.getCell(cellNum)` returns null on last row (and last row only); if I manually remove the autofilter from the workbook and run the parser again everything is smoothly going.
Has anyone experienced something like this before ?

One acceptable solution to my problem would be to remove the autofilter (I have to read all the workbook's rows anyways) from the file when reading but googling around and checking POI API's I didn't find a handle to getting if autofilter is set or how to remove it .

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Marco

Comment: Can you try with a more recent version of POI? 3.9 is fairly outdated, 3.14 is the current release and 3.15-beta1 is available in a few days...

Comment: Hi, the problem is that the application uses POI in other places thus I should re-validate everything. Although doable, I would prefer a solution for the specific problem. Will try the new POI version in test and let you know